# Firebase database empty tab, rules load indefinitely

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I just created a firebase project. And the database in the console appears empty. On previous projects, when you clicked on the empty white area, you were able to create database items by hand.

But clicking it doesn't do anything.

The rules tab is loading indefinitely, and i can't type anything.

I'm on Chrome last version, do you encounter such problems by creating new projects?

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Empty tab]

[image: Rules loading]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, quick answer to my own question as i wasn't able, from my Angular2 App, to interact with database as well via websocket.

I'm working in a company with a (strong) proxy setup file. Disabled it on windows settings and all works now perfectly. Firebase website appears to rely on websockets.

Hope this information can be useful to someone else!